# After denying an app network permissions, how do I explicitly allow an application to listen on a network port?

Tags: macos, network, security, permission, firewall

I just reinstalled my Macbook (Ventura) and started my privoxy server for the first time. A box popped up asking me if I wanted to allow this application to listen on a network port, or something to that effect, I forget the exact wording.

Anyway, I fat fingered the box away without accepting, and MacOS apparently took that to mean "Deny for ever". I have restarted privoxy, the terminal and the computer but I can't get the permission box back, and traffic to privoxy is being blocked.

I don’t know where to inspect or change the permissions I have denied on the Os.

Can I reset permission requests so MacOS asks me again or white list a denied app after that decision ?

Answer (score 1):

You should look for the application in the Firewall advanced settings of System Preferences and select "`Allow Incoming Connections`".

On Big Sur or later: System Preferences -> Network -> Firewall -> Options...

[image: Firewall advanced settings, System Preferences]